# Showing that roots of $1+\sum_i \frac{h_i^2}{1-2h_i+2h_i^2-x}$ lie in $(0,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $h_1,\ldots,h_d$ is a vector of positive numbers where $\sum_i h_i=1$ and $\sum_i h_i^2 < 1/5$.

What is the easiest way to show that all the roots of the following lie in $(0,1)$?

$$f(x)=1+\sum_i \frac{h_i^2}{1-2h_i+2h_i^2-x}$$

Roots of $f(x)$ [correspond](https://chat.openai.com/share/58aba738-2654-45b0-b4a7-54c3adc6d6cf) to roots of the characteristic polynomial of the linear map $g(v)=v-2(h\odot v)+2(h\odot h\odot v)+\langle h, v\rangle h$

Example, let $\hat{h}=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots,1/d)$ and $h=\hat{h}/\|\hat{h}\|$.

For $d=10$, all the roots are real and lie in $(0.62832.., 0.946269..)$. I would like estimate this range for arbitrary $d>1$, starting with bounds like (0,1) is the first step.
[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-prove-bounded-roots.nb)

[image]

Comment: That's not a polynomial.  Might help to note that if all the $h_i$ are equal the claim is true.

Comment: So we start with $d\geq 5$ .

Comment: Can you clarify the domain and co-domain of rational function $f$? Also does $\odot$ denote Hadamard product?

Comment: @user8675309 Yes, $\odot$ is pointwise multiplication and $f$ is complex valued function

Comment: No.  I don't believe $f: \mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is valid because e.g. $ \frac{h_1^2}{1-2h_1+2h_1^2-x}$ has a pole.  So I'll ask again, what is the domain and co-domain of $f$? (Maybe you mean $\mathbb C$ with finitely many real points deleted is the domain and the co-domain is $\mathbb C$)

Comment: Not sure what domain/co-domain should be, perhaps your suggestion is the best one. The motivation for this question is to obtain the range of eigenvalues of linear operation $g(v)$ in the question, known to be contractive. It appears these correspond with roots of $f(x)$, real valued and $\in (0,1)$, can realness and $(0,1)$ interval be shown rigorously?

Comment: $g$ seems to be a positve map in the Perron theory sense.  But having all eigenvalues real would be a bit surprising.  Note: you wrote "Example let $\hat{h}=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots,1/d)$ and $h=\hat{h}/\|\hat{h}\|$." But this violates your criterion of the squared two norm being $\lt \frac{1}{5}$ stated on line 1.  If the norm in the denominator is the one norm you should explicitly say it but even then I choose $d=2$ and get a contradiction.

Comment: Good catch, $d$ needs to be [greater than 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE3Pa.png) to satisfy the condition